# Не запускается exe-файл win-forms

Tags: c#, exe, inno-setup, setup

Всех приветствую, недавно написал одно приложение на WF и захотел собрать его в setup. Нашел утилиту, все сделал по гайду, даже установил при помощи мною созданного сетапа, но вот само приложение после установки не запускается. Кто сталкивался с похожими ситуациями, в чем может заключаться проблема?

P.S сам exe-шник из папки запускается и все работает, а вот после сетапа - нет

Comment: Проблема заключается в отсутствии всякой возможности продиагностировать проблему. С какими симптомами приложение не запускается? Текст или код ошибки есть?

Comment: Абсолютно никаких признаков жизни, пробую запустить - ничего не происходит

Comment: Откройте диспетчер задач, посмотрите, нет ли процесса с таким именем. Если есть - программа запускается, но по какой-то причине не отображает формочку. Можно ещё в отладчик её зарядить и посмотреть что происходит.

Comment: понял, спасибо!

Comment: Смотрите Event Log - Журнал событий.

Comment: Кроме того, сделайте логирование в своём приложении. Тогда по логу можно будет находить ошибки.

Comment: Благодарю, надеюсь поможет